# Assign min Value to char C++

Tags: c++, char, variable-assignment, min

I am trying to assign the min value of a char to a variable of type char array like this

```
char charchar_value[MAX_VARCHAR_LENGTH + 1]= CHAR_MIN;
```

it gives me this error "incompatible types in assignment of ‘char’ to ‘char [513]’"

Comment: You don't have a variable of type char; you have an array of chars.

Comment: That's not a `char` variable, that's a `char` **array** variable.

Comment: What are you trying to do? As it is now, you're creating an array and trying to initialise it with a `char`.

Comment: Your variable isn't "of type `char`". Rather, it is of type `char[MAX_VARCHAR_LENGTH + 1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialization of array object requires the use of brace initializer list, i.e. something along the lines of

```
char charchar_value[MAX_VARCHAR_LENGTH + 1] = { val_0, val_1, /*...*/ val_n };
```

This would initialize the first `n` values to their respective values and all others to zero. This isn't quite what you want. The only way to set the values in the array is after its initialization, using e.g. `std::fill()`:

```
std::fill(std::begin(charchar_value), std::end(charchar_value),
          std::numeric_limits<char>::min());
```

Since there is another suggestion recommending the using essentially a C approach:

- The use of `memset()` is limited to types without any C++ features (as is, indeed the case for `char`) and when setting the value to something other than `0` it is pretty much limited to `char` (yes, I realized that there are cases where it would still work). `std::fill()` on the other hand, works with any type which is CopyAssignable and with any value given to an object of the corresponding type.
- Although the use of `sizeof()` work in this case, it won't work the moment the size becomes dynamic but the compiler would still happily accept the code. Getting the `std::begin()` or `std::end()` of a pointer would fail.
- In a context where the type isn't exactly know, e.g. when it is a typedef or within a template, `std::numeric_limits<T>::min()` has a better chance to work. It still won't work for many type as there is not `min()` defined but the scope is bigger.

All that said, I would just use an appropriate class instead which does the initialization directly, i.e.

```
std::vector<char> charchar_value(MAX_VARCHAR_LENGTH + 1,
                                 std::numeric_limits<char>::min());
```

This allocate the memory dynamically, though, i.e. it isn't entirely equivalent. However, unless there is a good reason to assume otherwise, I would use the simple approach and only optimize if it is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to set the first element to `CHAR_MIN` then it would be:

```
char charchar_value[MAX_VARCHAR_LENGTH + 1] = { CHAR_MIN };
```

If you want to initialise the entire array to `CHAR_MIN` then it would be:

```
char charchar_value[MAX_VARCHAR_LENGTH + 1];

memset(charchar_value, CHAR_MIN, sizeof(charchar_value));
```

Comment: Yikes! `memset()`? Surely you meant `std::fill(std::begin(charchar_value), std::end(charchar_value), std::numeric_limits<char>::min());`

Comment: @DietmarKühl - Yikes nothing.  Please tell me your tongue was hiding in your cheek???  You may not prefer that style, but there is nothing inherently wrong or unsafe about using memset, CHAR_MIN, or sizeof().  Some who like more succint syntax would look at your "more modern" cross-example and have the same disgust you have at Paul's.

Comment: @phonetagger: nope, I meant it! Why teach anybody a rather limited approach if a more general and safe approach is available (see my answer for reference).

Comment: @DietmarKühl - I appreciate your answer, and am upvoting it.  My only issue is with the "yikes", as if there's something deficient, unsafe, or nonportable with Paul's answer.  Assuming it satisifies the needs of the OP's problem, then there's nothing deficient, unsafe, or nonportable about it.

Answer (score -1):

Determine the Min and Max values for the following data types in C++:

```
g)  char
h)  int
i)  float
j)  double
```